# Swing application performance issue with POI and FileOutputPutStream

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working on the maintenance of a swing application. In which the application fetches data from access database and populate it on excel file.
Till 100 records it works fine when populating more than 200 records application slows down, when i see task manager memory consumption it increase till 700 mbs.
the previous programmer was using Apache poi and FileOutputStrean that is properly closed.
I am note able to understand where is memory leakage problem.My code snippet is

```
                final ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> arrlist_b1 = new Model()
              .getAllowanceDetails1(
                currency,
                type,
                arrListYear,
                arrList_survey_name,
                arrList_country,
                arrList_company);

            final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
              "yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss");
            final Date date = new Date();
            XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook();

            FileOutputStream out1 = null;
            try {
             out1 = new FileOutputStream(
               new File(
                 filepath));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
             e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            XSSFSheet spreadsheet1 = workbook1
              .createSheet("Sheet Name");

            XSSFRow row1 = spreadsheet1
              .createRow(0);
            CellStyle style = workbook1
              .createCellStyle();

            style = new Style()
              .a_b_and_p_heading(workbook1);
            int count_column1 = 0;
            int count_row = 1;

            pb.setMaximum(arrlist_b1
              .size() - 1);
            int total=arrlist_b1
              .size();
            for (int a = 0; a < arrlist_b1
              .size(); a++) {
             pb.setValue(a);

             download_status
               .setText(a
                 + 1
                 + " / "
                 + total);
             System.out
               .println(a);

             LinkedHashMap<String, Object> tmpData = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) arrlist_b1
               .get(a);
             Set<String> key = tmpData
               .keySet();

             Iterator it = key
               .iterator();
             String hmData, created_by;
             XSSFRow row_tbl_heading = spreadsheet1
               .createRow(count_row);

             int count_column = 0;
             while (it
               .hasNext()) {
              String hmKey = (String) it
                .next();

              if (a == 0) {
               spreadsheet1
                 .autoSizeColumn(count_column1);
               XSSFCell cell_row = row1
                 .createCell(count_column1);
               cell_row.setCellStyle(style);
               hmKey = hmKey
                 .replaceAll(
                   "_",
                   " ")
                 .toLowerCase();
               hmKey = StringUtils
                 .capitalize(hmKey);

               cell_row.setCellValue(hmKey);
               count_column1++;

              }
              DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(
                "##,###");
              XSSFCell cell_row = row_tbl_heading
                .createCell(count_column);
              spreadsheet1
                .autoSizeColumn(count_column);

              CellStyle cellStyle = workbook1
                .createCellStyle();
              cellStyle
                .setDataFormat(workbook1
                  .getCreationHelper()
                  .createDataFormat()
                  .getFormat(
                    "##,###"));

              Object obj = tmpData
                .get(hmKey);
              if (obj instanceof Integer) {

               if ((Integer) tmpData
                 .get(hmKey) == -1) {
                cell_row.setCellValue("");
               } else {
                cell_row.setCellValue((Integer) tmpData
                  .get(hmKey));

               }

              } else if (obj instanceof Double) {

               if (Double
                 .parseDouble(tmpData
                   .get(hmKey)
                   .toString()) == -1.0) {
                cell_row.setCellValue("");
               } else {

                int round_val = new Validation()
                  .count_digit(tmpData
                    .get(hmKey)
                    .toString());
                cell_row.setCellFormula(("ROUND("
                  + Double.parseDouble(tmpData
                    .get(hmKey)
                    .toString())
                  + ",-"
                  + round_val + ")"));
                cell_row.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

               }

              } else {
               hmData = (String) tmpData
                 .get(hmKey);
               cell_row.setCellValue(hmData);
              }
              count_column++;
             }

             count_row++;
             arrlist_b1.remove(a);
             tmpData.remove(key);
             it.remove();

            }
            try {
             workbook1
               .write(out1);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
             System.out
               .println("hello+"
                 + e1.getMessage());
             e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
             out1.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
             // TODO
             // Auto-generated
             // catch
             // block
             System.out
               .println("hello+"
                 + e1.getMessage());
             e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The application did not respond after 400 records.
I use Jprofiler to trace memory usage where char[] and String is consuming a lot of memory.
Please let me know if where the memory leakage problem. thanks in advance.
I am attaching jprofiler snapshot.[image]

Comment: Maybe `workbook1.close()` after the `workbook1.write(out1)`?

Comment: It did not work ,The progress works fine till 100 records after that it slows down and after few minutes application does not responds.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]

Comment: How much memory did you give to the JVM as heap size?

Comment: 1024 mb heap size. Total  ram=8gb

Answer (score 0):

Get a debugger and step through the loops. My guess is one of the objects is not clearing out the memory on each iteration.  If you can't find it, you may need to load it in chunks at a time like 200 records at a time.

Usually prefetching the data into an array and processing that is quickest. Objects can be very heavy in Java.